# With AJAX how to show 2 type of validation errors of a input in different html elements?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

We have one input and this input have 2 validation. **First** is checking user input is *alphanumeric characters* or not and the **second** is *username already in use* or not.

I want to show if **first validation** trigger it the html element must be in **blue** color and the **second** trigger it it must be in **red** color.

Errors data coming from PHP by the way. I have 2 variables in PHP these are for showing errors. But in Javascript can't imaginated it what am I supposed to do.

**Here is Php:**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    //username validation
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    if (! $user->isValidUsername($username)){
        $infoun = 'Your username must be at least 3 alphanumeric characters';
        echo $infoun;
    } else {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT username FROM members WHERE username = :username');
        $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if (! empty($row['username'])){
            $errorun = 'This username already in use';
            echo $errorun;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**Here is Javascript and Html form:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){               
        
        $("#username").keyup(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var username = $(this).val().trim();
            if(username.length >= 1){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'registercontrol.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {username:username},
                    success: function(response){
                    // Show response
                    $("#uname_response").html(response);
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $("#uname_response").html("");
            }
        });         

    });
</script>

<form id="register-form" class="user" role="form" method="post" action="registercontrol.php" autocomplete="off">

<input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control form-control-user" placeholder="Your username" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES); } ?>" tabindex="2" required>

<!-- How to change div class based on php variables?  -->
<div id="uname_response" class="color-red"></div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check in ajax success function what `data` is been recevied using `if-else` and  depending on that just change your div color .

Your `success function` will look like below :

```
var datas =$.trim(response);//remove any whitespaces
if (datas == "This username already in use") {
//add class 
$("#uname_response").toggleClass("color-red")
  $("#uname_response").html(response);
} else {
//add class
$("#uname_response").toggleClass("color-blue")
  $("#uname_response").html(response);
}
```

**Demo Code** :

```js
//suppose this is been received
var response = "This username already in use";
var datas =$.trim(response);//remove any whitespaces
if (datas == "This username already in use") {
//add class 
$("#uname_response").toggleClass("color-red")
  $("#uname_response").html(response);
} else {
//add class
$("#uname_response").toggleClass("color-blue")
  $("#uname_response").html("something");
}
```

```css
.color-red {
  color: red;
}

.color-blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="uname_response" ></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers and it's a working solution too but I missed something. Ajax will response print whatever we give the php echo. So why we say to php:  `echo '<p class="p-3 text-info">'.$infoun.'</p>';` and another is possible for username already in use too. In this area we can decide what css class we use. It's works and simple solution with a little bit change.

Comment: yes that was also one solution :)  .Sorry i was not knowing you already got solution to your problem

Comment: Well actually after your answer i got an idea for that.